# Combining downloaded html template with php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Pls Honourables I need help,  I am new to laravel. I am done with setting up the laravel environment and having done some basic routing. I have this template which I downloaded with it files(css,js etc) the issue is I am not certain on which folder I should put it in order to access its css and js file aside from predefined laravel styles and bootstrap. Pls help me

Comment: Do you use these files directly or Laravel Mix instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should put this to your resources directory, and use Laravel Mix to copy it to the public directory.  Put this code in the `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
mix.copyDirectory('resources/template', 'public/template');
```

If you are not using Laravel Mix, then you can put it into the public directory.

For more info, [follow this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix),

Comment: Thanks very much, I copied the css, js, and image folder of the template to the public folder  then moved the pages to resource  folder.  It works tho I did not use mix.copyDirectory() hope it won't be an issue.

Comment: It won't be an issue, make sure if you are using git, your public directory isn't ignored.